# Display tilde (~) instead of home folder name when at home in macOS Terminal (zsh)

Tags: macos, zsh, terminal.app, appearance

How do I have

`~ $`

instead of

`myUsername $`

in zsh? My bash displays like the former and I like it because it looks cleaner.

My *.bash_profile*

```
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1
export PS1="\W \$ "
```

My *.zshrc*

```
export PS1='%1d $ '
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section *EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES* in the *zshmisc* manual elaborates on a lot of possibilities which information *zsh* offers out-of-the-box to display at the prompt.

In your specific case, to display the last folder of the current working directory, but shorten the homedir to `~` you should use the `%~` sequence:

> `%~`
>
> As `%d` and `%/`, but if the current working directory starts with
> $HOME, that part is replaced by a `~`.
> Furthermore,  if  it  has a named directory as its prefix, that part is replaced by a `~` followed by
> the name of the directory, but only if the result is shorter than the  full  path;  see  Dynamic  and
> Static named directories in zshexpn(1).

So, it essentially boils down to replace the `d` in your `PS1` with a `~`:

```
PS1='%1~ $ '
```